# Whats a good way to show errors/messages to users in php?

Tags: php, error-handling

I have been using my own method for years, but I figured maybe its not the best way to go about it.

Essentially when I want to throw an error to a user, or display confirmation of a successful action, I do the following:

```
if($something == "condition") {

   $_SESSION["message"] = "Your passwords didnt match! Make sure they are the same in both fields!";
   $_SESSION["message_type"] = 1;
   header("Location:register.php");
   exit();

}
```

then I have a function like

```
function show_message() {
   global $_SESSION;

   if (isset($_SESSION["message"])) { 
      echo "<div class='site_message type_" . $_SESSION["message_type"] . "'>" . $_SESSION["message"] . "</div>"; 
      unset($_SESSION["message"]); 
      unset($_SESSION["message_type"]); 
   }
}
```

and I put show_message(); on top of every page to display possible errors that might be throw to this page.

What are the possible problems with this?

Comment: What if the session doesn’t work as the client doesn’t accept cookies?

Comment: I was under the impression php handled that by passing SID thru the URL. EDIT: My impression was false, it didnt work. :o

Comment: Only thing I would add would be to turn these functions into methods of a dedicated class. Messaging used this way is often called flash messaging in various frameworks. So this could be the base of your FlashMessage class.

Answer (score 3):

I see nothing wrong with this approach. You'll find this technique under different names in quite a number of frameworks, for instance [FlashMessenger in Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html).
Usually the Session is wrapped in an object instead of the regular Session array and with a ViewHelper instead of a function.

To make sure you don't have any typos in the Session keys when assigning the message, you could wrap the assigning code into a function as well, e.g.

```
function set_message($text, $type)
{
    $_SESSION['message'] = array(
        'text' => $text,
        'type' => $type
    );
}
```

You could improve it by having the function *return* the string instead of `echo`ing it and personally I'd use `sprintf` to format the output. Makes the code somewhat more readable imho, e.g.

```
return sprintf('<div id="message-box" class="type-%s">%s</div>',
                $_SESSION["message"]["text"], 
                $_SESSION["message"]["type"]);
```

Like @Gumbo pointed out, the function might not work when Sessions do not work, but that will likely impose a number of other problems for the entire application then, so I wouldn't exactly bother about this particular piece of code then.

Minor thing: $_SESSION is a [superglobal](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php), so you do not have to use the `global` keyword.

Comment: @Yegor it's fine now. The `unset`s was on the same line as the echo.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I would do this not with Sessions, but with the URL.

Instead of setting a message, make a class that contains 'System Messages'

```
 class SystemMessages{
    protected $messages = array(
          0 => "Some Error Message");

    public function getMessage($id)
    {
        return $this->messages[$id];
    }
 }
```

Then, on your register.php, check for a URL parameter:

```
$messageObject = new SystemMessages;
if(!empty($_GET['message']))
{
    $message_id = intval($_GET['message']); // Clean User Input
    $message = $messageObject->getMessage($message_id);
    // handle message
}
```

If you are ONLY showing a message, then it really isn't 'sensitive' data, and therefore it should be perfectly fine to put it in the URL.

Then you just

```
 header('Location: register.php?message=0');
```

Works with/without cookies, and you it much more centralized. If you wanted to change the wording of a message, all of the messages are in the same place.

Just a thought....

Comment: It's common practice to use sessions for messages.

Comment: URL will look messy?