# Need best way to send error messages from One Webpage to another

Tags: php, urlencode, implode

What is the best way to send your messages like error messages from one php page to other php page.
I do not want to use  implode function, also i do not want messages to be displayed in address bar.
Using this code 
$pageurl.= '?errors[]=' . implode('&errors[]=', array_map('urlencode', $errors));
My error messages generated by entering incorrect information by user got displayed in address bar, which is something i do not want.
Kindly help.

Comment: Use POST instead of get? Lets see some code

Comment: Looks like you need to follow a tutorial about web development with PHP, maybe even one on HTTP alone. As above, use POST instead of GET.

Comment: Did you check this answer? I think this is a duplicate question.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/2205609

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use session data. It is stored on the server and kept between page loads.

Page that determines errors:

```
<?php
session_start():
// something happens here to cause errors
$_SESSION['my_error'] = array(
    'Field 1 is incorrect',
    'Field 3 is incorrect'
);
// whatever happens here to send user to next page
```

Page that displays errors:

```
<?php
session_start();
// check for set errors
if (isset($_SESSION['my_error']) && !empty($_SESSION['my_error']))
{
    foreach ($_SESSION['my_error'] as $error)
    {
        echo $error.'<br>';
    }
    // unset them if not needed anymore
    unset($_SESSION['my_error'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks to all for help.